# YouTube Ads and Playback Speed

Tags: youtube, ads

If you adjust the playback rate in your browser to speed through YouTube ads (but don't click the skip button), does the video uploader earn ad revenue as if you had played the ad at regular speed?

Answer (score 1):

**YouTube doesn't allow changing video playback speed during video ads.**

---

Playback options available on a normal video

[image: normal video options]

Playback options available during an advertisement

[image: advertisement video options]